# Parse the sccp layer from pcap file that contains the "sendAuthenticationInfo" packet

Tags: tshark

I have a pcap file that contains the sendAuthenticationInfo message.
I try to parse the sccp layer from this packet using tshark
I tried the following:

```
tshark.exe -r filter.pcap -T fields -e sccp > parse.bin
```

I know what the result should be from parsing manually in wireshark, the result I get is much shorter and different from expected.

Original packet:

```
d4 c3 b2 a1 02 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 f0 52 7a 57 9a d7 00 00
ba 00 00 00 ba 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 08 00 45 00 00 ac 00 00 00 00 10 84
ab cc 7f 00 00 01 7f 00 00 01 0b 58 0b 59 00 00
48 23 01 f3 c7 60 00 03 00 8c 00 00 1f 7a 00 01
00 00 00 00 00 03 01 00 01 01 00 00 00 7c 02 10
00 72 00 00 04 3a 00 00 02 4e 03 02 00 04 09 80
03 0e 19 0b 12 06 00 11 04 79 52 14 02 10 07 0b
12 07 00 12 04 44 87 92 97 01 08 44 62 42 48 04
00 00 00 01 6b 1e 28 1c 06 07 00 11 86 05 01 01
01 a0 11 60 0f 80 02 07 80 a1 09 06 07 04 00 00
01 00 0e 03 6c 1a a1 18 02 01 01 02 01 38 30 10
80 08 24 05 01 77 03 84 35 f8 02 01 01 83 01 00
00 00
```

expected result:

```
09 80 03 0e 19 0b 12 06 00 11 04 79 52 14 02 10
07 0b 12 07 00 12 04 44 87 92 97 01 08 44 62 42
48 04 00 00 00 01 6b 1e 28 1c 06 07 00 11 86 05
01 01 01 a0 11 60 0f 80 02 07 80 a1 09 06 07 04
00 00 01 00 0e 03 6c 1a a1 18 02 01 01 02 01 38
30 10 80 08 24 05 01 77 03 84 35 f8 02 01 01 83
01 00
```

result I got:

```
73 63 63 70 0d 0a
```

Comment: First, the *"Original packet"* you show isn't a packet at all but a hex dump of a [pcap][1] file.  Second, "sccp" is a protocol, not a field, so `-e sccp` most certainly isn't going to work.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

[1]: https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat